# What exactly is the difference in the meaning of the words 'opinion' and 'perspective'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I have been thinking about the words perspective and opinion for quite sometime.
I see them used a lot by many like "Your perspective is not same as mine, which is perfectly fine" and "Your opinion is purely subjective and so is your perspective".

Do the words mean the same or completely different from each other?

Comment: *Perspective* and *opinion* are highly related. In short, *opinion* is your thought about something, and *perspective* is the way of your thinking.

Comment: So can my opinion result in me having a particular perspective ?

Comment: I would say it's the other way around. To me, it's more like a particular perspective will influence a particular opinion. The word "perspective" is usually refers to the way we view the world from a specific point of view (or "viewpoint"). Seeing the world through this perspective, of course, must influence how we see things, and how we have our opinions on them.

Comment: Perspective change when we see or come across other individual's opinion. In that way can't we think that even opinions change one's perspective ? I understand that perspective is far more objective than an opinion. Am i correct in thinking so?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps this steps toward the realm of philosophy. I agree that our perspective can shift over time. Reading or hearing someone else's opinion can change our mind. I agree that we can think of perspective objectively (a bit easier from a third-person's viewpoint). But usually one's perspective is subjective (it depends entirely on that person), and so are their opinions.

Answer (score 9):

The word "perspective" in this context is a metaphor. To help contrast it with "opinion," let's first dive into the literal meaning of "perspective."

Imagine that we are both looking at a building, but you are standing on a mountain looking down at it while I am looking at the front door. The *perspective* you have is your view. To you, the building looks small. "From your perspective, it is small." To me, the building looks big. "From my perspective, it is big." Our perspectives are different. For instance, you have a better perspective for gaining information about the roof of the building. I have a better perspective for counting the number of wood panels in the door. This is the *literal* meaning of the word perspective. In this context "opinion" makes no sense. It sounds funny to say "In my opinion, the building is big, and in your opinion, it is small." We are both intelligent adults who agree that the size of the building is an objective fact about reality, so it doesn't make sense to formulate an opinion on it.

Now, let's imagine we are debating agricultural policy, say, banning Chemical X. If you are a farmer, and I am not a farmer, metaphorically, we can say we have different perspectives on this policy. You see what you see in the fields (you need to be allowed to use Chemical X or a billion ants will eat your crops), and maybe this causes you to dislike the policy. I see what I see in my village (ever since you started using Chemical X, the water is purple and people are getting sick), and maybe this causes me to like the policy. We have different perspectives. We can inform each other of our perspectives, but, just like the people looking from the mountain, we can never really "see" what the other person "sees." You may think angrily that I have never worked on a farm and have no idea how horrible the ant problem is. I may think that you don't see what happens when your chemicals seep into the river. Now it makes sense for the perspectives to inform our opinions about whether the policy is good or bad.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer! I love your detailed explanation of the literal meaning of the words, and how you fleshed that out to come to your conclusion. I wish I could upvote this more than once!

Answer (score 0):

A perspective can be factual an opinion is always subjective. People have different perspective about social movements based upon solid evidence. A diamond has different angles that gives it value. An appraiser does not offer an opinion about the cuts but can give a perspective as to why one cut is more expensive from one part of the world and not in another.

Akbar